# How do I get the string value of the tuple in Django

Tags: python, django, tuples

This sounds like a noob question, I just want to ask how do I get the string value of this tuple.

```
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'PQA'),
    (2, 'Tester'),
    (3, 'Test Lead'),
    (4, 'Test manager'),
    (5, 'Senior Test Manager'),
    (6, 'admin'),
)
user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

When I call the value as:

```
<h1> {{ user.user_type }} </h1>
```

It shows up as the int value and not the string.

It sounds very simple but I can't seem to find it on the python documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I prefer to use a method to get the attribute, and constants to declare choices, like Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Like this example:

```
Class ModelName(models.Model):
    ...
    PQA = 1
    TESTER = 2
    TEST_LEAD = 3
    TEST_MANAGER = 4
    SENIOR_TEST_MANAGER = 5
    ADMIN = 6
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'PQA'),
        (2, 'Tester'),
        (3, 'Test Lead'),
        (4, 'Test manager'),
        (5, 'Senior Test Manager'),
        (6, 'admin'),
    )
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

    def get_user_type(self):
        return dict(self.USER_TYPE_CHOICES).get(self.user_type)
```

On template:

```
<h1> {{ user.get_user_type }} </h1>
```

This allows you to use the constants in your code:

```
if user_instance.user_type is ModelName.TESTER:
    ...
```

Which is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Using PositiveSmallIntegerField will only show index numbers, you can use `models.CharField()`

```
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('PQA', 'PQA'),
    ('Tester', 'Tester'),
    ('Lead', 'Test Lead'),
    ('Manager', 'Test manager'),
    ('SeniorManager', 'Senior Test Manager'),
    ('Admin', 'admin'),
)

user_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

You may need to recreate the database and do the migration operations following [this link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) to make the new string choices working.

Comment: I've changed it as you have suggested but it still shows up as an int. I've already made migrations but it's still showing as int

Comment: It may have your previous data and it has been stored as integers and then transferred to string after new migration. 
If I were you, I will [recreate the database](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) and do the migrations again.

Comment: Scratch that it worked.Apparently I have to refresh the settings but yeah it works! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Aces, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('PQA', 'PQA'),
    ('Tester', 'Tester'),

)
user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: its because your user_type is ""PositiveSmallIntegerField"" try CharField